# Reading delimited string messages out of NSData from FileHandle through CFSocket

Tags: objective-c, sockets, nsdata, filehandle

i am receiving string messages over a socket connection and as i am receiving the bytes from the associated filehandle i create a string from them.

```
[NSString stringWithCString:[data bytes] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
```

now this kind of works fine but as i tried to log these strings i get them correctly most of the time but in between i get some garbage characters. i tried it with utf8bytes and with ascii like above (the messages are ascii anyway).

i am receiving data through notifications like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveData:) name:NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification object:fileHandle];
[fileHandle waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];
```

i suppose that once the load of messages increases, the mangled string parts show up in the log. the message itself is clean and strictly alphanumeric (plus the delimiter @";" and dots in floats)

or do the weird string parts have nothing to do with the messages and i just got it wrong using the socket to read the data?

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably munging up your data with the way you are converting it. Data is not guaranteed to be delivered in perfect C style string boundaries. Calling `stringWithCString` is reading each data buffer delivered up to the null character then disposing any bytes remaining. You should accumulate all your data buffers before performing any conversion.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. but when is it safe to do a conversion if i have a more or less continuous stream of text coming in. i could put the data in a buffer and always scan up to the next delimiter, but maybe you could give me a hint on how to approach this. the scanner scans strings so there's the conversion problem again, right? would i have to go and examine the data character for character?

Comment: ok, i think i'll get through this eventually. it is a problem with my conversion so forget about the comment above. thanks for the help!